# Convert list into dict(dictonary). Proc-bridge communication

Tags: java, python, dictionary, casting, type-conversion

I'm using https://github.com/gongzhang/proc-bridge lib to communication beetwen python and java code. I need to pass to java code list but I can pass only dict type. Example code looks like:

```
host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 8077
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

def request_handler(api: str, arg: dict) -> dict:  #-> here that dict
    if api == 'echo':
        return list
    elif api == 'add':
        return {'result': sum(x for x in arg['elements'])}
    else:
        raise Exception('unknown api')

server = ProcBridgeServer(host, port, request_handler)
server.start()
```

There is an option to cast list to looks like that (or maybe change it to pass just list) :

List: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

after cast Dict : [1,2,5,6,7,8,9 : 3,4] ? where 1,2,5,6,7,8,9 are values and 3,4 are both keys

Comment: Would recommend passing data to and fro using JSON or XML

Comment: but how when in lib i have just this dict

Comment: Add a bit more explanation to the question, unable to understand what you want exatly

Comment: just cast list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] to dict = [1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9:3,4]

Comment: That is wrong format, and exatly why i am not able to make sense of it

Comment: ok i think that we don't understand each other. So the point is to cast list to some kind of dict. But whole list with 9 elems will be just one pair (value/key). Exactly dict should looks like {'1','2'....'9':'3','4'}

Comment: Or in simplier i have list with personal data of person which looks like 
data = [32,180,John,Terry,Brown,70] and I want to made dict which looks like {'32','180','Brown','70': 'John','Terry'} point is that on left side we have data like age, height, eye color, weight and on right side name, surname :)

Comment: I think if you can only pass dicts you should pass it like `dict={'list':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]}`

Comment: i would avoid using list as a variable name in python as it is the name for a built in function.

Comment: @BengBeng So if i understand right, you want to have a list of values as a value for a key in dict? and the list for key 3,4 is the same list in the example you gave

Comment: @en_lorithai my suggestion was to pass the array as value and a name as key. I am not suggesting to use 'list' as key, it can be anything.

Comment: @HimanshuBansal my comment was supposed to be directed to BengBeng. Sorry for not making that clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will convert your list to a dictionary

```
alist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
adict = {}
for value in alist:
    adict[value]=value
```

If the list won't contain a simple range of numbers you could use

```
alist = ['oof','hey',3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
adict = {}
for index in range(len(alist)):
    adict[index]=alist[index]
```

Or the simpler version

```
alist = ['oof','hey',3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
adict = {'someKey':alist}
```

Comment: can I add more keys ?

Comment: @BengBeng yes, simply do adict['newkey'] = value